# Deactivate selection by letter in JList

Tags: java, swing, key-bindings

I've got a JList list and the following code line:

```
list.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke('d'), "action");
```

So when my list is in focus and I press the **d** key on my keyboard an action should be performed. That action takes into account which item of my JList is currently selected. The problem is that whenever there is an item in my list with first letter 'd' my selection will jump to that entry first and then do the action (applied to the wrong item).

So my question is: How do I disable those selections jumps in JLists caused by typing a letter?

Comment: One silly idea - have you tried putting an invisible space in front of your item names?

Comment: @pvg I just tried it and it works ;). But that's not the way I want to solve the problem. And now I have a problem with assigning an action to the space bar ;). Or what do you mean by invisible space? I just took a normal one.

Comment: No, try an invisible unicode space, not an actual space. I think it's actually a pretty decent solution that doesn't dig excessively into the default and fairly-implementation-specific details of JList.

Comment: @principal-ideal-domain you have to override, to disable `JList#getNextMatch` by returns - `return -1;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove the [KeyListeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyListener.html) from the JList.
I tried but couldn't figure out what this breaks in terms of standard functionality.

```
KeyListener[] lsnrs = list.getKeyListeners();
for (int i = 0; i < lsnrs.length; i++) {
    list.removeKeyListener(lsnrs[i]);
}
```

Comment: There is one `getClass` too much and even with fixing that typo it doesn't work.

Comment: @principal-ideal-domain - Works for me :)

Comment: I'm using a self written table model. Does that change anything?

Comment: @principal-ideal-domain - TableModel does not matter. But the Listener approach indeed only works in Java8. Try the NoSelectionModel  approach.

Comment: @Leet-Falcon wouldn't option 2 pretty much break list selection? If you can't properly select on the list, there's not much point having keyboard shortcuts that act on the selection.

Comment: I'm using Java 8: java.runtime.version: 1.8.0_66-b18

Comment: @principal-ideal-domain - You are right. Option 2 breaks the selection.

Comment: @principal-ideal-domain - Sorry, it was the standard listener (javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicListUI$Handler) which you need to remove.

Comment: The following code works for me: `for (KeyListener keyListener : list.getKeyListeners()) {
   if (keyListener.getClass().getSimpleName().equals("Handler")) {
    list.removeKeyListener(keyListener);
   }
  }`

Comment: @principal-ideal-domain This is a great question with a truly terrible accepted answer. Option 2 is broken and Option 1 is so fragile, it only works in one particular JDK. It's completely dependent on the implementation details of JList - it can end up not working in JDK 8+N. The invis character thing is a hack, but at least it's robust. An even better alternative is to simply not use JList. Use a JTable and style it to look the same.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of removing the KeyListeners, override the `getNextMatch()` method of JList to return -1 every time. Then it won't jump to the selection by letter on key press.

```
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.text.Position;

class CustomJList extends JList<Object> {

    @Override
    public int getNextMatch(String prefix, int startIndex, Position.Bias bias) {
        return -1;
    }

}
```